# Using the microsoft Calendar API in PHP

Tags: php, calendar, office365, outlook-restapi

I am trying to connect with calendar by following [url](http://localhost/php-calendar/home.php)

I am using this script https://github.com/jasonjoh/php-calendar

When I hit connect to my calendar then I want to redirect on:

```
localhost/php-calendar/o365/authorize.php
```

But it gives me the following url after redirect:

```
localhost//php-calendar/error.php?errorMsg=Error+adding+event+to+calendar%3A+Request+returned+HTTP+error+403
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Provide a screen shot of error.

Comment: Let us know which browsers have you tested this on.

Comment: Checkout this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/327003/-http-403-forbidden-error-message-when-you-try-to-access-your-mailbox-through-outlook-web-access

Comment: I am using firefox

Comment: Try with other browsers too. Mention all the browsers you have tried on in your question not in comments so that it will be easy for community to understand your post. Also do post a screenshot of error.

Comment: Please include the relevant code from authorize.php and the response from the calendar API or the login.microsoftonline.com service used to authenticate the user.

Comment: I am using  this Office365Service::addEventToCalendar($accessToken, $event->title, $event->location,
  $event->startTime, $event->endTime, $attendeeString); then I got this error Array ( [errorNumber] => 401 [error] => Request returned HTTP error 401 )

Comment: @RasmusW can you help me?

Comment: @Promith please update the question with the source code that you use to authenticate towards Office 365, and subsequently use to access the calendar API. I'm guessing that you are using https://github.com/jasonjoh/php-tutorial, but it's not really something that can be determined from your question. Also, the Office 365 Graph API normally returns more detail than simply a 401 error. I don't know the PHP O365 Calendar API you are using, so I don't know how to get hold of that.  You are new to Stackoverflow, so you may benefit from http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @RasmusW  I am using this script https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/02/26/using-the-calendar-api-in-php/